# In bash how do I print the first C style comment from a file

Tags: bash, parsing, comments

I'm looking for a bash one-liner to print the comment at the top of source files that contains the copyright information.  Calling the command on these examples should produce the described output.

```
/*
 * copyright 2004
 */
package Foo
...
```

Should print the first three lines

```
/* copyright 2004 */
package Foo
...
```

Should print the first line

```
package Foo
/* some other comment */
...
```

Should print nothing

I think it should be fairly easy to do in perl or awk, but I can't seem to get it to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This awk command seems to work with the given input, but it is probably not reliable enough for general use:

```
awk 'NR==1&&/^\/\*/{s=1}s==1{print $0}s==1&&$NF=="*/"{s=0}' test.c
```

In order for it to print the output, the first line should start with `/*`, and it will print all lines until it reaches a line that ends with `*/`.

Update: In order to work with whitespaces before the `/*` and with blank lines in the beginning of the file, we can use this command.

```
 awk 'NF==0&&s==0{NR=0}NR==1&&$1=="/*"{s=1}s==1{print $0}$NF=="*/"{s=2}' test.c
```

Comment: You are right. It doesn’t work if there is whitespace characters before `/*` and if there is an empty line at the beginning.

Comment: @thefourtheye Now it should also work in the cases you mention, but I am sure that there are more cases we have not thought of... :-)